# How to deserialize XML result from a HTTP POST request in Java?

Tags: c#, java, xml, xml-serialization, http-post

In C#, I make an http post and get an xml in the response in the form of a byte array (bret), which I deserialize into a class easily:

```
MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream(bret);
XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TransactionResults));
TransactionResults t = (TransactionResults)s.Deserialize(m);
```

What would be the correct and easiest way to do the same in Java?

Comment: Feel free to edit the title into something more correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your POST request via something like

http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.net/post.html

or use HttpClient:

http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/methods/post.html

Depending on how you have serialized your data, you should use a corresponding de-serializer.  XStream is a good simple choice for such tasks:

http://x-stream.github.io/

All of this is admittedly more code, but this is a typical tradeoff of .NET vs Java systems (although it's more code, there are advantages to Java).

Answer (score 0):

Using [X-Stream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html) - for a get request :

```
XStream xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver());
xstream.alias("person", Person.class);
URL url = new URL("www.foo.bar/person/name/foobar");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
Person foobar = (Person) xstream.fromXML(in);
```

You can modify the call to url for a [post](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html).

Answer (score 0):

[JAXB is the Java standard](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/07/jaxb-xml-binding-standard.html) ([JSR-222](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222)) for converting objects to XML with multiple implementations:  [Metro](http://jaxb.java.net/), [EclipseLink MOXy](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) (I'm the tech lead), [Apache JaxMe](http://ws.apache.org/jaxme/).

The HTTP operations can be accessed in Java using code like:

```
String uri =
    "http://localhost:8080/CustomerService/rest/customers/1";
URL url = new URL(uri);
HttpURLConnection connection =
    (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");

JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
InputStream xml = connection.getInputStream();
Customer customer =
    (Customer) jc.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(xml);

connection.disconnect();
```

The above code sample is from:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-45.html

For a comparsion of JAXB and XStream see:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-xstream.html

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to map your result into classes, you might want to check out [Resty](http://beders.github.com/Resty/).
It makes accessing JSON, XML or any other data type a one-liner.
Here is code that parses the Slashdot RSS as XML and prints all the linked articles.

```
Resty r = new Resty();
NodeList nl = r.xml("http://rss.slashdot.org/Slashdot/slashdotGamesatom").get("feed/entry/link");
for (int i = 0, len = nl.getLength(); i < len; i++) {
    System.out.println(((Element)nl.item(i)).getAttribute("href"));
}
```